# Using select_related in add/edit django admin for single field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to resolve the N+1 problem.

Below is my model:

```py
class Work(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey('Chapter', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey('Job', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    prev_work = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

And now I overrided get_queryset in my ModelAdmin.
It works great in List View but when I want to add new element it makes multiple queries because of the "book" field. So how can I override sql for SINGLE field.
To be specific, it makes so many queries because in my model file I have this:

```py
  def __str__(self):
        return self.book.project.slug + "-" + str(self.book.number) + "-" + self.job.name
```

and there are many books and many projects.
My ModelAdmin for Work:

```py
class WorkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super(WorkAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).filter(
            book__state = 0).select_related(
                'book', 'book__project', 'book__project__title', 'job', 'user').only(
                    'book__number', 'book__project__title__name', 'job__name', 'user__name')
    list_display = ('book', 'job', 'user')
    fields = ('book', 'job', 'user')
```

Comment: What about `.select_related('book', 'book__project', 'job')`?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, seems like add/edit panel doesn't use  get_queryset form ModelAdmin.